# Rules of thumb in the design of stringers and frames for hull design

Tags: frame

In the design of boat hulls (and aircraft) reduction in material thickness is important and the hull is usually made as an assembly (welded or riveted) with stringers and frames. The design of stiffened panels is a complex problem. Are there a set of simplified rules for the design of stringers and frames for boat hulls?

Comment: Geodesic construction? but not sure if that is used on boats...

Comment: @PhilSweet If you convert your comment into an answer I can accept it. I didn't know the term _scantling_  and now the search engines are working for me. I knew about BV & Lloyds but they work on something bigger than what I was looking for. Gerr's book (from what I've seen in "Look Inside") is what I'm looking for and is affordable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called scantling rules. Herreshoff and Nevin had scantling rules for wooden yachts. Classification Societies such as Lloyds and BV have scantling rules for ships. Gerr's *Boat Strength* has rules for small boats covering several hull materials.

Comment: +1 For that was an amazing piece of trivia.

Comment: And as steel strength is increased ,be sure to specify higher toughness . The Coast Guard has rules for ship design and materials to be used in US waters.